# TextArea Not Displaying Content Until Resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm having an issue with loading values to a textarea in my form.

---

Here's its CSS:

```
textarea.form_field
{
border:1px solid #D4D3DA;
color:#3B3C3F;
background-color:#FCFCFC;
font-family:Century Gothic, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:700;
letter-spacing:0px;
top:0px;
text-align:left;
width:100%;
height:83px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-left:4px;
padding-right:4px;
margin-top:-1px;
scrollbar-arrow-color:#3B3C3F;
scrollbar-face-color:#F6F6F8;
scrollbar-highlight-color:#FFFFFF;
scrollbar-shadow-color:#BEBEC0;
scrollbar-3dlight-color:#F6F6F8;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#F6F6F8;
}
```

---

Here's its markup:

```
<textarea class="form_field" name="P_DESCRIPTION" id="P_DESCRIPTION" fieldname="Project Description" rows="3" fieldcheck="true"></textarea>
```

---

Here's the script that I am setting its value with:

```
function loadform()
{
var tbval = "Here is the value\nHere is a new line for the value\n\nHere is your mom";
document.getElementById("P_DESCRIPTION").innerText = tbval;
}
```

---

Here's what's happening:

User goes to the form (.asp page), enters values, then submits the form. The form reads and records values, then sends the user back to a view version of the form, which shows them all of what they recorded.

Onload of the view version calls the loadform() function, which loads all of the user's data to the form. It successfully loads all of the data, however, only the first line of content is visible in textareas. The remaining content is hidden (though present, because you can move the cursor through it and highlight it) until the page is resized.

This is kind of a big issue and I can't figure out why it is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you go any third party CSS libraries like Bootstrap that may be over-riding some of your styles ?

Comment: What happens if you define a `cols` attribute on the `<textarea>` and remove the `width` attribute from your CSS?

Comment: @splig: No, there is no third party CSS.

Comment: @Cory: You are correct. Removing width:100% from css and adding cols="20" to the markup corrected the issue. This causes a new problem for me, in that I need the textareas to resize with the form.

So, I tried a couple things. 
1- I added style="width:100%;" to the textarea's markup, after the setting of cols. This appeared to fix both issues, however, when I scrolled down my form to observe the 3 other textareas present on the form, I found that the issue was only corrected for the first textarea displayed.

Comment: @Cory: 
2 - I added the 100% width back into my stylesheet and left cols set in the markup. This was no help and made the problem return for all textareas.

3- With cols set in markup, no width set in CSS, I added a javascript function to the form to be called on load and resize, that sets the width of all textareas on the document to 100%. This seems to be the best fix, as the issue is not present on any of the textareas now.

Comment: @user3560594: I'm guessing that the browser just doesn't know how to calculate the actual width of the text (because your font has variable width characters) so it has no idea where to wrap the text (at least initially). Adding `cols` fixes that because now there's a measurable area where the text needs to fit. Triggering a resize on the textarea must force it to recalculate the line breaks, so maybe that is a good solution for now.